# Get data from local html file to variable tampermonkey script c#

Tags: html, tampermonkey

How to get data from my local html file?

path: file:///C:/WORK/data/sample.html

inside the sample.html

```
<div class="row">
<label class="">Business Name:</label>
<div class="data">Sample Businessname</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label class="">Website Address:</label>
<div class="data"><a href="https://sample.com/" target="_blank">https://sample.com/</a> </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the word "Sample Businessname" and "https://sample.com/" and pass to variables using C#.

Answer (score 0):

First install HtmlAgilityPack

please see the [documentation](https://html-agility-pack.net)

you can install by opening Package manager Console and using this command

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

Than this should do the trick you can test it in a new console application so you understand how it works

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String path = @"C:\Users\jakpod01\Desktop\Sample.html";

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);

        var businessNameNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='row']/div[@class='data']");
        String? businessName = businessNameNode?.InnerText.Trim();

        var websiteAddressNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='row']/div[@class='data']/a");
        String? websiteAddress = websiteAddressNode?.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty).Trim();

        Console.WriteLine($"Business Name: {businessName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Website Address: {websiteAddress}");

        // TODO: Pass the extracted data to Tampermonkey variables or do whatever you need to do 
    }
}
```

Please change the path variable to reflect your path to the file

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the data directly to tampermonkey variables without using any application? I'm sorry for my confusing question above.

Comment: what do you mean without any application ? the C# code has to run somewhere @YevrahAradnop